# Do we pronounce the name of G-d in Aleinu?

Tags: tefilla, shemos-sacred-names, aleinu-leshabeiach

I noticed in Aleinu that at the end, we say "בַּיּוֹם הַהוּא **יִהְיֶה יְהוָה** אֶחָד". I was wondering if someone could tell me about the origins of this line. Specifically, when we say יִהְיֶה are we pronouncing HaShem's name? I'm not fluent in Hebrew, so I apologize if this is a dumb question.

Comment: The word יהיה means “He will be” in Hebrew. The second word is Hashem’s name. So the line is saying “on that day, Hashem will be one”

Comment: Yes, it is not a name for Hashem, but you were confused for a good reason - the similarity in the letters is because Hashem's 4 letter name is, in part, connected to the concept of eternal time: "was" "is" and "will be". When you look at the hebrew words for all of those, you can see the connection; all similar letters and roots. See: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/84276/31534

Comment: This is a relatively late addition to the text https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92054/759

Comment: It is worth noting that when Zechariah first said it, it might have been an alliteration.

Comment: Why is the title here, "Do we pronounce the name of G-d in Aleinu?" Surely the word _following_ the one you mentioned is the name of G-d and is pronounced. Could you explain the question?

Answer (score 2):

And HaShem will be king over all the earth.  On that day HaShem shall be One, and His name One. [Zechariah 14:9]

Comment: See as well the end of the question: "Specifically, when we say יִהְיֶה are we pronouncing HaShem's name?"